# I updated App ScreenShots but it is not live on Google play?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I updated App ScreenShots before 3 days even though in google play store it showing the old screenshots of my app. I did this in new version of Google console. May i know the reason why it is not get updated and please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you get a notification saying *Your Update is Live*?

Comment: No,I didnt get any notification,But other than my screenshots apk,description and all got updated

Comment: Okay. Do you see *Your update is being reviewed* on GPC? Did you test on any other smartphone? It may be old cache showing on your smartphone(if that's the case)...